# Debugging MS Word Macro for importing JPGs that is returning duplicate images

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking through the following macro I inherited and trying to figure out why it's importing duplicate images when it pulls unique photos from the same folder. Any help would be much appreciated, I don't have a lot of experience with VBA.

The purpose of the macro is to pull all image files in the same folder as the word document and embed them in the word document itself. Right now it's taking the first image in the folder and embedding it multiple times. I think it's an issue with the loop logic but I'm pretty new to VBA and having trouble fixing it.

```
Option Explicit

Dim msPath As String
Dim msPictures() As String
Dim mlPicturesCnt As Long


Public Sub ImportJPGFiles()
On Error GoTo Err_ImportJPGFiles

Dim lngCount As Long
Dim lngPicture As Long
Dim strMsg As String

Dim sngBEGTime As Single
Dim sngENDTime As Single

    
'Assume JPG files are in same directory as
'as the Word document containing this macro.
msPath = Application.ActiveDocument.Path & "\"
lngCount = LoadPicturesArray

'Let user browse to correct folder if pictures aren't in the same
'folder as Word document
While lngCount < 0
    strMsg = "Unable to find any JPG files in the following" & vbCrLf & _
             "directory:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
             msPath & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
             "Press the 'OK' button if you want to browse to" & vbCrLf & _
             "the directory containing your JPG files.  Press" & vbCrLf & _
             "the 'Cancel' button to end this macro."
    
    If (MsgBox(strMsg, vbOKCancel + vbInformation, "Technical Difficulties")) = vbOK Then
        With Application
            .WindowState = wdWindowStateMinimize
            msPath = BrowseForDirectory
            .WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
        End With
        If LenB(msPath) <> 0 Then
            If Right$(msPath, 1) <> "\" Then
                msPath = msPath & "\"
            End If
            lngCount = LoadPicturesArray
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sngBEGTime = Timer
For lngPicture = 0 To lngCount
    Application.StatusBar = "Importing picture " & _
                            CStr(lngPicture + 1) & " of " & _
                            CStr(lngCount + 1) & " pictures..."
                            
                            
    With Selection
        .EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        .MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=21, Extend:=wdExtend
        .Copy
        .EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        .InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
        .Paste
        .MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=24
        .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=msPath & msPictures(lngPicture), _
                               LinkToFile:=False, _
                         SaveWithDocument:=True
    End With

    
Next lngPicture
sngENDTime = Timer

strMsg = "Import Statistics: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
         "Pictures Imported: " & CStr(lngCount + 1) & vbCrLf & _
         "Total Seconds:     " & Format((sngENDTime - sngBEGTime), "###0.0") & vbCrLf & _
         "Seconds/Picture:   " & Format((sngENDTime - sngBEGTime) / (lngCount + 1), "###0.00")

MsgBox strMsg, , "Finished"

Exit_ImportJPGFiles:
With Application
    .StatusBar = "Ready"
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
Exit Sub

Err_ImportJPGFiles:
MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, , "ImportJPGFiles"
Resume Exit_ImportJPGFiles
End Sub

Public Function LoadPicturesArray() As Long
On Error GoTo Err_LoadPicturesArray

Dim strName As String

strName = Dir(msPath)
mlPicturesCnt = 0
ReDim msPictures(0)
Do While strName <> ""
    If strName <> "." And strName <> ".." _
    And strName <> "pagefile.sys" Then
        If UCase(Right$(strName, 3)) = "JPG" Then
            msPictures(mlPicturesCnt) = strName
            mlPicturesCnt = mlPicturesCnt + 1
            ReDim Preserve msPictures(mlPicturesCnt)
            'Debug.Print strName
        End If
    End If
    strName = Dir
Loop
    
Call QSort(msPictures, 0, mlPicturesCnt - 1)

'    Dim i As Integer
'    Debug.Print "----AFTER SORT----"
'    For i = 0 To mlPicturesCnt - 1
'        Debug.Print msPictures(i)
'    Next i

LoadPicturesArray = mlPicturesCnt - 1


Exit_LoadPicturesArray:
Exit Function

Err_LoadPicturesArray:
MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, , "LoadPicturesArray"
Resume Exit_LoadPicturesArray
End Function

Public Sub QSort(ListArray() As String, lngBEGOfArray As Long, lngENDOfArray As Long)
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim strPivot As String
Dim strTEMP As String

i = lngBEGOfArray
j = lngENDOfArray
strPivot = ListArray((lngBEGOfArray + lngENDOfArray) / 2)

While (i <= j)
    While (ListArray(i) < strPivot And i < lngENDOfArray)
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    
    While (strPivot < ListArray(j) And j > lngBEGOfArray)
        j = j - 1
    Wend

    If (i <= j) Then
        strTEMP = ListArray(i)
        ListArray(i) = ListArray(j)
        ListArray(j) = strTEMP
                        
        i = i + 1
        j = j - 1
    End If
Wend

If (lngBEGOfArray < j) Then QSort ListArray(), lngBEGOfArray, j
If (i < lngENDOfArray) Then QSort ListArray(), i, lngENDOfArray

End Sub
```

Comment: I agree. Read this: http://cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx Then come back when you have identified the problem. That's a lot of code. You should be able to narrow it down to the **Minimum Repeatable Example** that is required to ask a question here.

Comment: If you haven't yet, please check this help post that will tell you how to ask a question that will get a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'd guess the issue is somewhere in the copy/paste your code does within the Word document.  Put a break right after the `.Paste` and step through the code while checking what's happening in the Word file.

Comment: You might want to have a look at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16772-4-digital-images-1-page.html